# Prove that $\mathbb{R}^m$ is flat

Tags: riemannian-geometry, curvature

I am trying to prove that vector space $\mathbb{R}^m$ with Euclidean metric is flat, i.e. the sectional curvature at any point is 0. I use the definition of sectional curvature at a point

$K(u, v) = \dfrac{g(R(u, v)v, u)}{g^2(u, u)g^2(v, v) - g^2(u, v)}$, where $u, v$ are linearly independent tangent vectors at the same point

$K(u, v) = 0$, if $g(R(u, v)v, u) = 0$

$g(R(u, v)v, u) = g(\nabla_X\nabla_YY - \nabla_Y\nabla_XY -\nabla_{[X, Y]}Y,X) = g(-\nabla_Y\nabla_XY,X)$ and here I am stuck. 
Am I right with my calculations? If so, how to continue it?

Comment: Where do you get the last equality from?

Comment: As I understand $\nabla_YY = 0$ and so is $[X, Y]$, so only one term is left in the first argument of $g$

Comment: In Euclidean space with the standard metric the covariant derivatives commute, so the whole curvature tensor is identically 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $Z =\sum_{k} Z^k\partial_k$.  Then, in the Euclidean metric, we have
$$\nabla_X\nabla_YZ = \sum_{k} \nabla_X(Y(Z^k)\partial_k) = \sum_{k}X(Y(Z^k))\partial_k.$$

Use the commutativity of the partial derivative (since we are assuming the space is Euclidean) to show that 
$$\nabla_X\nabla_YZ- \nabla_Y\nabla_XZ = \nabla_{[X, Y]}Z$$ 
by expanding each term in the equation as I did above. Your result follows.